# Conversion of String with Abbreviated Timezone to Timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone

I have a timestamp stored as varchar2 in `May 29 14:12:56 PDT 2015` format. I want to convert this into `timestamp with time zone` data type.

If I use,

```
with x(dt_string) as (
  select 'May 29 14:12:56 PDT 2015' from dual
  )
select dt_string,
to_timestamp_tz(dt_string,'Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZD YYYY') dt_ts
from x;
```

it gives me,

```
DT_STRING                 DT_TS
------------------------  ----------------------------------------
May 29 14:12:56 PDT 2015  29-MAY-15 02.12.56.000000000 PM +00:00
```

Time zone is incorrect.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216) says,

> The TZD value is an abbreviated time zone string with daylight saving information. It must correspond with the region specified in TZR.

Does this mean `abbreviated time zone string` should have `Time zone region` to perform proper conversion? But, having `Time zone region` will make
`abbreviated time zone string` redundant. Isn't it?

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your query should raise error `ORA-01857: not a valid time zone` or `ORA-01882: timezone region not found`

`PDT` is not a valid time zone region, i.e. it is ambiguous. Run this query to get different meanings of `PDT`:

```
SELECT tzabbrev, TZ_OFFSET(tzname), tzname
FROM v$timezone_names 
WHERE tzabbrev = 'PDT'
ORDER BY 2;

TZABBREV    TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME)   TZNAME
PDT -06:00  America/Inuvik
PDT -07:00  US/Pacific-New
PDT -07:00  America/Ensenada
PDT -07:00  America/Dawson
PDT -07:00  America/Dawson_Creek
PDT -07:00  America/Los_Angeles
PDT -07:00  America/Tijuana
PDT -07:00  America/Vancouver
PDT -07:00  America/Whitehorse
PDT -07:00  Canada/Pacific
PDT -07:00  Canada/Yukon
PDT -07:00  Mexico/BajaNorte
PDT -07:00  PST
PDT -07:00  PST8PDT
PDT -07:00  US/Pacific
PDT -08:00  America/Juneau
```

You have to use `PST` as time zone region. Daylight saving settings are then determined from given day:

```
SELECT 
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('Jan 29 14:12:56 PST 2015','Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR YYYY') dt_ts_winter,
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('Jun 29 14:12:56 PST 2015','Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR YYYY') dt_ts_summer 
FROM dual;

DT_TS_WINTER                            DT_TS_SUMMER
2015-01-29 14:12:56.000000000 -08:00    2015-06-29 14:12:56.000000000 -07:00
```

Since your values are stored as `VARCHAR2` (now you know why you should not do it like this) you can change it with `REGEXP_REPLACE(dt_string, 'PDT', 'PST')`