# How to convert PDT into a date time object in Oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

If I have dates that are in this format: `Sep-29-07 13:45:00 PDT`

How would I convert this into a Date object in oracle 11g? I have tried this:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(PublishDate, 'MON-DD-YY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM Order;
```

But I am getting an error saying:

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: Do you have any other timezone's dates? If not, Do you plan to support them in future?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh No I do not have any other timezone's. Every single row in the table has that as the public_date value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one time zone's dates, you can just ignore the timezone part using:

```
select to_date(PublishDate, 'MON-DD-YY HH24:MI:SS "PDT"') 
from Orders;
```

If you plan to support multiple timezones, then store them with `timestamp with time zone` format. use correct timezone abbreviation (PST instead of PDT - [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484378/conversion-of-string-with-abbreviated-timezone-to-timestamp)) and convert the string, use `to_timestamp_tz`.

```
select to_timestamp_tz(PublishDate, 'MON-DD-YY HH24:MI:SS TZR') 
from Orders;
```

or perhaps, convert them in one local time zone. [See this answer for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089859/oracle-convert-timestamp-with-timezone-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the timezone by using:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SUBSTR(PublishDate, 1, length(PublishDate) - 4), 'MON-DD-YY HH24:MI:SS')
```

However, if you want to handle different timezones, you need to store the standard format, something like `'America/Los_Angeles'`.

For example:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(PublishDate, 'MON-DD-YY HH24:MI:SS TZR')
from (select 'Sep-29-07 13:45:00 America/Los_Angeles' as PublishDate from dual) x;
```

You can this modify this with `'PDT'`, but that is not acceptable by itself.